# How to acces JavaFX fields via Annotation?

Tags: java, javafx, annotations

What I'm trying to do:
I have a Java program in which I use JavaFX. I created a fxml file in which I created JavaFx controllers, which I then declared in the **AddEmployeeOrderController** class. I would like to transfer these created  controller fields to a POJO. Since I think it is very time-consuming and leads to a lot of careless mistakes, I wanted to automate this process more. My idea was to make an annotation for each declared JavaFX controller field so that, for example, all annotated fields are gonna be retrieved automatically at for example a push of a button in another method. So you can understand it that way instead of writing everything by hand yourself, e.g.:

```
EmployeeDto employeeDto = new EmployeeDto(textfield.getText(), textfield2.getText()..);
```

I first formed the **AddEmployeeOrderController** and declared some JavaFX field and added an annotation. Again in the **AddEmployeeOrderController** class I tried to access the annotated field.

Then, logically, I would have to cast to cast the java.lang.reflect.Field to a JavaFX TextField, but that is obviously not possible. It throws only IllegalArgumentException errors, and of course because you can't cast a java.lang.reflect.Field to a JavaFX TextField.

Is there a way in which my idea can be achieved with the help of annotation, or am I forced to write everything by hand and generate so-called boilerplate code.

```
 public class AddEmployeeOrderController implements Initializale {
     @FXML
     @MyAnno
     public TextField orderDateFromTextField;

     public void atPushButton() {
         for (Field field : AddEmployeeOrderController.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
             if (field.isAnnotationPresent(MyAnno.class)) {
                 if (((Field) object).getType().getCanonicalName()
                                               .contains("TextField")) {
                     TextField textField = (TextField) field.get(this);
                     textField.getText();
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }

 @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
     public @interface MyAnno {
 }
```

Comment: Could you explain what your coal actually is? What do you want to achieve with this mechanism?

Comment: Start here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx

Comment: Why are you doing `Object object = field;` if all you do is immediately cast that back to a `Field`? Just use the `Field` reference. And if you want to get the values of the fields from the controller instance then you need to pass the controller instance to `Field#get(...)`.

Comment: yeah, 'Object object = field'; is obsolete, some leftover from my previous attempts. But as I understand you right, 'Textield textfield = (TextField) field.get(orderDateFromTextField)' will do it? Because I dont think so, it will generate the same exception.

Comment: No. `AddEmployeeOrderController controller = ...;`. Now you have an instance _of the controller class_. You get the `Field` from the class of the instance and then you call `Object value = theField.get(controller)`. But make sure the instance referenced by `controller` (or whatever field/variable you use) is the same instance as used by your UI.

Comment: I am sorry, I am initiating the for loop method in the same **AddEmployeeOrderController** method. Creating an instance of the class where the TextField is placed an then, as you said, calling it in  `Object value = theField.get(controller.myTextField)` works fine. But that stiil does no solve my problem. I would have to cast it to TextField in order to obtain the input text from that field via getText().

Comment: How could `theField.get(controller.myTextField)` work fine for you? You are not getting a field from the `TextField` class and so passing an instance of `TextField` to `get` should throw an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not provided sufficient (relevant) code to understand what you are actually doing.  However, we can deduce the following:

1. The `Field` class you are using is `java.lang.reflect.Field`.
2. According to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get-java.lang.Object-), the `Field.get(Object)` should be called with a reference to an instance ... or `null`.  If an instance is provided, then it needs to be an instance the class that declares the field, or a subclass of that class.
3. If `Field.get` is called with a  parameter that is NOT of the required class, `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown.

So ... if what you have told us and shown us is correct ... `this` is not the correct object to be passing to `Field.get` on that `Field` object.

You are saying that the field reflection code you are showing us is in the `AddEmployeeController` class.  That means that `this` would be a `AddEmployeeController` instance.  But the `Field` instances you are iterating are for the fields declared by the class `AddEmployeeOrderController`.  So, you **should** be calling `get` with a (non-null) value that refers to an `AddEmployeeOrderController` instance.  (Or maybe you should be iterating the declared fields of `AddEmployeeController`.  Without more context it is difficult to say what the correct fix is.)

---

If we strip away all of the dynamic / reflective stuff, what your code is doing is analogous to this non-reflective code:

```
public class AddEmployeeOrderController {
    public TextField someField; 
}

public class AddEmployeeController {
    public void someMethod() {
        TextField t = (TextField)(this.someField);
    }
}
```

It won't compile because `AddEmployeeController` doesn't have a field called `someField`.

What you actually need to do is the analog of this:

```
public class AddEmployeeController {
    public void someMethod(AddEmployeeOrderController aeoc) {
        TextField t = (TextField)(aeoc.someField);
    }
}
```

---

Just to clarify, the problem is not coming from the typecast in

```
(TextField) field.get(this);
```

If the typecast was failing, then the exception would be a `ClassCastException`.  The exception you are seeing comes from the `get` call!

And the problem is not due to annotations.

---

**FOLLOW-UP**

I have taken your (attempted) MRE, factored out the JavaFX stuff, and turned it into working code.  My version shows how to extract a field value reflectively by matching the field's type and an annotation.

```
package test;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnno {
}

// End of MyAnno

package test;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class MyTest {
    @MyAnno
    public String someField = "Hi Mom";
    
    public void doIt() throws Exception {
        for (Field field : this.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (field.isAnnotationPresent(MyAnno.class)) {
                if (field.getType().getCanonicalName().equals("java.lang.String")) {
                    String value = (String) field.get(this);
                    System.out.println(value);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new MyTest().doIt();
    }
}
```

Note that this is REAL code.  It compiles, runs and ... works.  Try it.  If you change `String` to (say) `TextField`, you can adapt it to your problem.  (The actual type of the field is almost entirely irrelevant to the core problem.  As you can see.)

(One thing that could be improved and simplified is that the type test should use `Class.equals` rather than testing the name of the class.  It is cleaner and more reliable.)

One of your concerns was (I think) that you would need a lot of boilerplate code to make this work for your problem.  I don't think that is the case:

1. If I declare an abstract superclass for `MyTest` and put the implementation of `doIt()` there ... **it should just work**.  Notice that `doIt()` uses `this.getClass()` to get the current object's class.
2. It would also work if `doIt()` was in an unrelated class, provided that the method had an argument for passing the target Object.
3. It would even be possible to parameterize this on the type of the field.  Or look for fields that are subtypes of a given type.  And so on.  (Hint: you would need to pass the type as a `Class` object.)

---

I said "(attempted) MRE" for a reason.  In fact, your code doesn't compile.  Indeed, you have a variable (`object`) which is not declared, and whose intended type and purpose is hard to fathom.  I have assumed that it was a mistake, and guessed that your intention was to use `field` there.  *But I should not have to guess!*

A **real** MRE needs to be complete and compilable (unless your problem is how to get it to compile).  Ideally it should also be runnable, and running the MRE should reproduce the problem you are asking about.

The point is that we (people trying to help you) need to be **sure** that we understand **what** your problem is.  That is the **purpose** of the MRE.

Comment: Yes, everything you say is correct, only my question and also my goal is, as I wrote it: to pass the TextField via annotation and then to do, for example, getText () on the via annotation passed TextField, the exactly same which I declared in AssEmployeeController class. As you say, and as I also said, is it not possible to cast java.lang.reflect.Field onto a  TextField JavaFX ..? So what would be another possibility, whereby I absolutely have to make use of annotations!

Comment: If my updated answer still doesn't make sense to you, please update the question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that we can see *exactly* what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks again for your interest, I've rewritten my question, hope that's not a problem. Believe now should be what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes.  I see you have done that.  I believe that it doesn't invalidate anything I have written in my answer, and ... indeed ... that my answer would help you solve my problem if you understood it.  However, I think that the only way we will be able to *convince* you is if you write a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Koala read the referenced help page and act accordingly

Comment: @Stephen C **AddEmployeeController** was a typo, of course I meant all the time **AddEmployeeOrderController**. The example in your answer is understandable, but does not answer my question. My question was, how to do it with Annotations, because I will not feel compelled to write by hand every field into into a method. So far I have stuck with the fact that I cannot cast Field to Textield.

Comment: I think we are going to stay stuck then ... unless you put in the effort, and write us a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @StephenC okay, undestand, I did it, hope it is okay now!

Comment: Is my question going to be reopened again?

Comment: It depends.  I will vote.  But you took such a long time (20 hours) to add the MRE that the question may have dropped off the radar.  Lesson: if you want help ... listen, don't argue.

Comment: I saw your edit and you are right with listening not arguing. Thanks anyway, I 've got a lesson but I've learned a lot.